# Android custom browsing

Tags: android

For my little brother's school project, he has to create a text field and a button. Upon clicking that button, the app should extract anything written inside the text field and open it in the default browser. Example, if user writes hello, on clicking the button the default browser should search google for hello. I know how to open a specific URL using webview or intents. But after searching internet also couldn't find the answer for this. Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Custom Tabs give apps more control over their web experience, and make transitions between native and web content more seamless without having to resort to a WebView.
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Answer (score 0):

here's your answer:
 your MainActivity.java Should be like

```
     package com.tgs.sampleweb;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText SearchBox;
    Button btnSearch;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        SearchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String toBeSearch = SearchBox.getText().toString();
                String url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+toBeSearch;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and your activity_main.xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.tgs.sampleweb.Main2Activity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:hint="Search Here"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

hope this helps you